# Unable to make Guava base64 encode/decode work

Tags: java, base64, guava

It seems there is a very silly mistake somewhere as the following hello-world program is not working for me.

```
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

String hello = "hello";
junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(
    hello.getBytes(),
    BaseEncoding.base64().decode(
            BaseEncoding.base64().encode(hello.getBytes())
    )
);
```

I even tried `hello.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")`

What am I missing?

Comment: Two byte arrays, even if they contain the same values, are not equal. There is an assertion verifying that two arrays are equal, but JUnit 3 is so old that I can't remember the name of the method. Probably something like `assertArrayEquals()`.

Comment: Definitely agree this is more likely to be incorrect usage of JUnit than incorrect usage of Guava.

Comment: Good idea explicitly specifying the charset, that's a common source of bugs. In both `.getBytes()` and (if you use it) `new String()` you should always specify a charset explicitly. The [`StandardCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) class makes this easy - just use `UTF_8` everywhere a charset is expected and you'll (almost) never go wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays (confusingly) do not override `Object.equals()` (similarly they don't override `.toString()`, which is why you see those [useless `\[Lsome.Type;@28a418fc` strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402/113632) when you print an array), meaning that calling `.equals()` on two equivalent arrays will not give you the result you'd expect:

```
System.out.println(new int[]{}.equals(new int[]{}));
```

This prints `false`. Ugh. See *Effective Java Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays* for more.

Instead you should use the static helper functions in the [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class to do these sort of operations on arrays. For example this prints `true`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(new int[]{}, new int[]{}));
```

So try `Arrays.equals()` or JUnit's [`Assert.assertArrayEquals()`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])) instead of `Assert.assertEquals()`:

```
junit.framework.Assert.assertArrayEquals(
    hello.getBytes(),
    BaseEncoding.base64().decode(BaseEncoding.base64().encode(hello.getBytes())
    )
);
```

This should behave as expected.

Answer (score 3):

If you instead check if the String matches then it does match.

```
        junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(
            hello,
            new String(
                    BaseEncoding.base64().decode(
                            BaseEncoding.base64().encode(hello.getBytes())
                    )
            ));
```

What your check is looking at is the address, I do not know why.  If you look at the values in the byte[]'s you see they match.

```
        System.out.println("hello.getBytes = " + Arrays.toString(hello.getBytes()));
    System.out.println("decoded = " + Arrays.toString(BaseEncoding.base64().decode(
            BaseEncoding.base64().encode(hello.getBytes())
    )
    ));
```

which outputs:

```
hello.getBytes = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
decoded = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```